# Passing a Parameter - ReportViewer local mode

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, reportviewer

Am tyring to pass a parameter in a local report using a ReportViewer control in VS2010.  The user clicks on a merchant, and there is a button press (not shown) which then renders the report.

I've tried using this video : [How-to Pass Parameter to Report Viewer - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=sXJmRHgSAS8&vq=medium)

**Problem:**  Code doesn't work - near xxxx at the bottom I can't figure out what should be in there

**Problem:**  I would love to get rid of this code and use linqtosql or something simpler.

[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet1TableAdapters.MerchantNamesTableAdapter merchantNamesTableAdapter = new DataSet1TableAdapters.MerchantNamesTableAdapter();
        ddlMerchants.DataSource = merchantNamesTableAdapter.GetDataAllMerchants();
        ddlMerchants.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlMerchants.DataValueField = "MerchantUID";
        ddlMerchants.DataBind();
        ReportViewer1.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
        var newDataSet = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from merchant where merchantUID = @MerchantUID";
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MerchantUID", ddlMerchants.SelectedValue);
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(newDataSet);

        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource(xxxx, newDataSet.Tables(0));

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That xxxx is simply the name of the Datasource that you want to have. it can be anything and is used to by the constructor to [Construct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportdatasource.reportdatasource%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) a named data source. Its simply an identifier . Like pass "Merchent_Redemptions" or whatever u like.

Answer (score 2):

In scenario like this I usually follow this path:

- I create a dataset for the report: select the report and the menu command View - Report Data; in  the Report Data windows select New ... - Dataset. I enter a name for the dataset (suppose Redemptions) and I select New ... next by DataSource, then I select Object and I navigate to my domain (or dto) class. That done I see the fields of my class and I can use it in the report;
- If needed I create parameters in the Report Data Windows (right click on the Parameters Node) and define the name and type of the parameter;
- I write this code to pass the data and parameters (if needed) to the report:

  ```
  viewer.Reset();
  ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource();
  // I use a service/repository; you could also use Linq2Sql or EntityFramework 
  IList<Redemption> redemptions = _service.GetRedemptions(merchantId);
  BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(redemptions, string.Empty);
  dataSource.Name = "Redemptions";
  dataSource.Value = bindingSource;
  viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(getDataSource(sourceInfo));
  String reportName = "AD.Conso.MyReport.rdlc";
  viewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = reportName;

  IList<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
  parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("myParameterName", "myParameterValue"));
  viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
  viewer.RefreshReport();
  ```
- Note: I took this code from a project where I am using it in a slight different context, so some code could be not necessary in your context.

Answer (score 0):

The datatable is being used as a constructor rather it should be written as an index..

Below is the code present
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource(xxxx, newDataSet.Tables(0));

The code should be in this format
ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource(xxxx, newDataSet.Tables[0]);

Answer (score 0):

If u have dataAdapator, DataSet then try this on form load:-

```
    this.DataTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDatabase_DataSet.tableName, parameter01, parameter02);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```